# meetup api request open_events

Tags: javascript, api, meetup

I am trying to retrieve a list of open events in a certain category from meetup via api call through jQuery / JavaScript.

I entered the keys in the meetup console (https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/console/?path=/2/open_events) and receive a result that is workable. However, when I am trying to recreate the call on my website or even on hurl.it, I run into authentication problems.

The result is:
"details": "API requests must be key-signed, oauth-signed, or accompanied by a key: http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/#authentication",
"code": "not_authorized",
"problem": "You are not authorized to make that request"

However, I am passing the authorization request as headers
sign: true
key: api key I received from meetup

I am confused when it comes to all the different forms of authentication that meetup wants or offers (api, oauth1, oauth2). I simply want to display the list of events to users of my site. What is the best way of going about that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your request after the "open_events?" segment. If there is an ampersand right after that question mark, try deleting it. Some people have found this resolves the issue.
2. Check your "http" calls to be sure they are all in the form "https", not just "http", because this can also cause the error.

Comment: At first glance, this answer looks like a new question or "I am having this problem too" instead of a real answer. That's why it was flagged by Stack Overflow's automated review system.

Comment: I have deleted the portion of the answer that reflects that I had the same problem and resolved it.  I've numbered the answers to help people identify both of them. I'm at a loss as to how anyone could think this answer represents a new question.

Comment: It was flagged automatically by the system and added to the "Low Quality Posts" for human moderators to review. Two moderators voted to recommend deletion. They must have only read the first paragraph of your original answer...